# First fundamental form under parabolic coordinate

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, conformal-geometry

Given a parabolic coordinate system $x=\frac{1}{2}(u^2-v^2), y=uv, z=z$. I have to find the first fundamental form. There are standard techniques (just for ref. Andrew Perssley and many others). The ans is $(u^2+v^2)(du^2+dv^2)+dz^2$.

The question : Is there any way to find this from conformal mapping.

Comment: When you say $z =z$, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: This is notational abuse... see this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabolic_cylindrical_coordinates

Comment: So it seems you are just parametrizing $\mathbb R^3$ using $u, v,z$. So where is your submanifold that you want to calculate its second fundamental form?

Comment: Sorry I was wrong.. Please allow me to correct the question. It will be metric/ first fundamental form.